# Search for line and paste as column until next match

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I'm wondering if this is possible, more for curiosity's sake, but also it might be useful to know.

I have several ascii data tables and I want to combine them all into a single file. So I combined all of the files into a single file with the file name to signify the start of the new data. What I'd like to do is search for that filename as a sort of delimiter, yank it, and put it as a column into all subsequent rows.

For example:

```
file-1.txt
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
file-2.txt
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8
```

And turn it into:

```
file-1.txt 1 1 1 1
file-1.txt 2 2 2 2
file-1.txt 3 3 3 3
file-1.txt 4 4 4 4
file-2.txt 5 5 5 5
file-2.txt 6 6 6 6
file-2.txt 7 7 7 7
file-2.txt 8 8 8 8
```

It might be easier to do outside of vi, but I thought I might ask.

(I suppose another question along the same vein I'm not sure about is if you can put a yanked word as a column over several rows)

Answer (score 3):

**vim (it's ugly)**

```
g /\S/ if getline('.') =~# '^file' | d | else | norm! PJ | endif
```

- `/\S/` match none blank line
- `if getline('.') =~# '^file' | d` delete line starts with "file" to default register. Note that default register is line wise after deletion.
- `norm! PJ` paste above current line from default register, join them with a space. `J` insert one space if 1st line doesn't end with `.`, `!` or `?`, other wise it insert two spaces. also check `:h 'joinspaces'`. As `D.Ben Knoble` pointed out, you can replace it with `put! | join` if you want to avoid `normal` command.

But vim is not a proper tool to do this kind of job, `awk` is much better.

**awk**

```
awk '/^file/{p=$0; next} {print p, $0}' filename
```

Comment: Not bad, the join, forgot about that. Could be `put | join`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Updated. It's `put!` in this case.

Comment: pretty cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You had a secondary question about inserting a word as a column in a table. It's possible using Visual select in block mode and we can use this method, as you probably surmised, to solve your primary problem as shown by the following series of commands.

*The first two answers use approaches that are generally better (easier to follow, less error prone) than what follows here. Consider this a bonus answer...for educational purposes.*

Put the cursor on a file line (e.g. `file-1.txt`) to start. Note that where you see `^R` that means to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Similarly for `<Esc>` enter <kbd>ESC</kbd>...

- `DJ` - delete-yank the text and move everything up a row with the `J`oin.
- `^V/^file/-1` - start Visual select (block mode) and extend it to the line preceding the next delimeter line.
- `I^R" <ESC>` - Do a block insert of the filename (found in unnamed register `"`) followed by a space. Every selected row will get this text. That's our column insert magic.
- `'>j` - Go to the line after the last line of previously selected text. We're ready for the next iteration.

We can create a recursive macro out of a slight variation of these commands. Play the macro and the whole file will be converted into desired format. One caveat: you must have a blank line at the end of file. This is preventable but I was in a hurry. :)

Here's the macro (almost) ready for insertion into register `q`....

```
DJ^V/^file\|^$/-1^MI^R" <Esc>'>j@q
```

I say "almost ready" because you can't just copy/paste this into Vim. Like before `^R` means `Ctrl-R` but to actually enter this text so you can yank it into register `q` you'll need to precede each control-character (and `<Esc>`) with `Ctrl-V`. So where it says `^M` you'll actually enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Great trick! I'll certainly use this "column insert magic."

I've been using vim for years but nothing with registers. I have some reading to do.

Comment: Registers mostly play a supporting role here (Visual block mode select/edit is the star) but regardless reading up on them is a good idea. They make a lot of things easy that would otherwise be difficult or impossible.  And a few of them are pretty "magic"...especially the expression register `"=` (I wouldn't start with that one, though! Relatively advanced stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern we'll be using is: insert text at the beginning of a range of lines.

We have two options:

- `:[range]normal! Itext`
- `:[range]substitute/^/text`

I tend to think of `normal!` first, because of the insertion, but the substitute should work just as well. We're going to use substitute here, because it's easier to insert dynamic text at the end of.

---

Start by defining a function to do most of the work:

```
function Work() abort
  " delete and capture the file.txt line
  delete a
  " trim newlines and add a space
  let @a = trim(@a) . ' '
  " insert the value on all lines up to the next '.txt' line
  .,/\.txt\|\%$/-1 substitute/^/\=@a
endfunction
```

**Edit**: I was able to eliminate the range error by using `\%$` as I had been trying to do in my experiments. But the key was that we need a blank line at the end.

We need a bit of prep, because the function uses the pattern `/.txt\|\%$/` as part of a range, so we need a blank line at the end if none exists—`:s/\%$/\r`,
or alternately, `:call setline('$', '')`, `:call append('$', '')`, or even `:$normal! o`. We can inspect visually, of course, but for the scripter:

```
if len(getline('$')) > 0
  call append('$', '') " or whichever variant you prefer
endif
```

Then do it with a global command:

```
:global/.txt/call Work()
```

---

Altogether, then, create a script-file called `whatever_you_want.vim` with the following contents:

```
function Work() abort
  " delete and capture the file.txt line
  delete a
  " trim newlines and add a space
  let @a = trim(@a) . ' '
  " insert the value on all lines up to the next '.txt' line
  .,/\.txt\|\%$/-1 substitute/^/\=@a
endfunction

if len(getline('$')) > 0
  call append('$', '') " or whichever variant you prefer
endif

global/.txt/call Work()
```

Now start vim with

```
$ vim /path/to/your/file.txt -S /path/to/vimscript.vim
```

Optionally, add to the end of your script

```
write
quit
```

if you're quite sure of the results.

The script has the benefit of being embarrassingly repeatable.

---

**N.B.** This function was crafted specifically to your example. It will definitely fail if any of your "data" contains `.txt` somewhere.